# Custom Laravel Artisan command not available through cron job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cron

I have custom Artisan commands that run locally as well as on my production server when I am SSH'd in, but are unavailable to any cron jobs. I've even tried running it as the user the cron job runs as and it works fine from my console.

When I run `php artisan` in the above settings, my custom commands are listed and available. However, they are not listed when I run `php artisan` as a cron job.

Furthermore, trying to run the custom command `php artisan subjects:calculate` as a cron job results in the following error:

`[InvalidArgumentException]

There are no commands defined in the "subjects" namespace.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was fighting with the same error and I found the solution.
First failed attempts

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/artisan my:command

*/5 * * * * php /home/mysite/public_html/artisan my:command
```

Solution

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/artisan my:command
```

Comment: That's the one! I thought I had posted my answer here when I found it but I must have forgotten. Actually specifying the full path to php on the server and then the full path to the file made it work.

Comment: I had godaddy hosting and this answer resolved my issue as well. I was working on laravel 4 for conjob and got resolved by his command. May I know what is `/local/` keyword is required in the path?

Comment: Just find where your PHP binary is installed by using `which php` and then reference it in that location.

Comment: What is the logical answer for this issue? Looks like the php command aims the same place. Why this works so wild!? This solves also mine problem - but I'm curious why is like that?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to add the command to app/start/artisan.php file:

```
Artisan::add(new SubjectsCommand);
```

or if you are using the IOC container:

```
Artisan:resolve('SubjectsCommand');
```

Then run the CronJob from the folder of the app:

```
00 09-18 * * 1-5 php /path/to/yourapp/artisan subjects:calculate
```

or

```
00 09-18 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/php /path/to/yourapp/artisan subjects:calculate
```

Comment: The command is set up and works properly from the command line. It only doesn't work when being accessed through a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

At least for me that worked:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        // Commands\YourCommand::class,
    ];
}
```

Just added my command to the list of command kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You probable need to make sure artisan is running from the correct directory

```
cd /path/to/yourproject && php artisan subjects:calculate
```

Comment: It is running artisan from the correct directory, running `php artisan` does list all the commands, but my custom ones aren't available. The actual cron runs `php /path/to/myproject/artisan subjects:calculate`.