# laravel custom command not listed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have created a custom command called `confirmUserCommand` with the filename matching the class name (same case). The $name is set to `confirmuser`.

Running the command `php artisan list` displays the new command on my local, but not on the server (which is running linux). I did perform a composer dump-autoload and update the relevant composer files to no avail.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: See my answer in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35247944/241279 Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tore my hair out and found out the issue..

In order to list the artisan commands including the custom ones, you have to invoke the systems PHP CLI Intepreter specifically PHP call.

`php artisan list` : would list all the commands as expected but not the custom commands you created

`php-cli artisan list` : This would list the all commands including the custom commands created

Hope this helps someone and save their hair :)

Answer (score 30):

Laravel 5.2 ~ 5.5:

Create your command & edit

```
   protected $signature = 'order:check'; //or whatever you want your command to be
```

You will have to find where the commands are created & edit the `app\Console\kernel.php` file.

in this file under

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\OrderCheck::class,
]
```

run again

```
 php artisan list
```

It should be listed there :)

Comment: I don't understand why it is not pointed the same in Laravel manual. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of Laravel it's not longer needed to register the commands, just be sure that the console command class name is the same as the file that hosts it.

App/Console/Commands/MyCommand.php -> class MyCommand ...

Comment: Indeed! In my case the problem was my class name was singular, but class file name was plural and thus not matching.

Answer (score 1):

From laravel version 5.6 onwards you need not make the entry of your custom command in `app\Console\kernel.php`

Answer (score -1):

In order to make it appear in the php artisan list you need to add it to the App/http/Kernel.php file specifically in the  commands array:

```
 protected $commands = [
   'App\Console\CreateSlugsCommand',....
];
```

After you do that you can  run in your console `php artisan list` and you  you will see the custom command.