# How to setup scheduler in Laravel-4.2 and Above version

Tags: php, mysql, scheduler, laravel-4.2

I created job.php at ..\app\commands\

```
public function fire()  {
    $this->dailyAt('09:00', function(){
    Mail::send('emails.test', array(), function($message) {
             $message->to('address', '')->subject('subject')->attach('path');
         });
    });//end daily
 }

protected function dailyAt($time, callable $callback){
    if(date('H:i', $this->timestamp) === $time) call_user_func($callback);
}
```

I put 'php artisan cron:run' on command prompt manually, it runs perfectly.  How could I schedule this?  I know there is something like * * * * *, however, I have no idea how to use of * * * * *

I am using Laravel-4.2

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to create a cron job.
you can do this by adding the command into a crontab.
in cli from the root of your project type `crontab -e`,
and then add your command.

```
/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php pathto/artisan namespace:command
```

where 
 `/10 * * * *` is the time(this will launch at every 10 minutes), `/usr/bin/php` the location of php cli, and `pathto/artisan namespace:command` is the location of the command that will be executed.
Example:

```
/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/fooproject/artisan cron:run
```

More [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988323/custom-laravel-artisan-command-not-available-through-cron-job) , and something about [cronjobs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/crontab-every-10-min/).